# Parse log file in python

Tags: python, parsing, notepad++

I have a log file that has lines that look like this:

```
"1","2546857-23541","f_last","user","4:19 P.M.","11/02/2009","START","27","27","3","c2546857-23541",""
```

Each line in the log as 12 double quote sections and the 7th double quote section in the string comes from where the user typed something into the chat window:

```
"22","2546857-23541","f_last","john","4:38 P.M.","11/02/2009","
What's up","245","47","1","c2546857-23541",""
```

This string also shows the issue I'm having; There are areas in the chat log where the text the user typed is on a new line in the log file instead of the same line like the first example.
So basically I want the lines in the second example to look like the first example.

I've tried using Find/Replace in N++ and I am able to find each "orphaned" line but I was unable to make it join the line above it.
Then I thought of making a python file to automate it for me, but I'm kind of stuck about how to actually code it.

---

Python errors out at this line running unutbu's code

```
"1760","4746880-00129","bwhiteside","tom","11:47 A.M.","12/10/2009","I do not see ^"refresh your knowledge
^" on the screen","422","0","0","c4746871-00128",""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) is smart enough to recognize when a quoted item is not finished (and thus must contain a newline character).

```
import csv
with open('data.log',"r") as fin:
    with open('data2.log','w') as fout:        
        reader=csv.reader(fin,delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='^')
        writer=csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', 
                          doublequote=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in reader:
            row[6]=row[6].replace('\n',' ')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Just now saw the edit. It works, however, it throws a "list index out of range" after going through about 1750 lines in the text log. I'm guessing it is running out of memory because the original text file is about 352,000 lines?

Comment: @NewShinyCD: Hm, I don't think memory should be a problem, because the csv reader steps through the file line by line without saving past lines. If you are getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` on the line of code `row[6]=row[6].replace('\n',' ')`, it may be because there is a syntax error in the data file. If you'd like some help with that, post the traceback message and the text around line 1750 in the log file.

Comment: I edited the original post with the line where that error occurs. I'm guessing it is because of the caret symbol at the beginning?

Comment: @NewShinyCD: You are right -- the caret is part of the problem. In particular, the double quote after the caret needs to be interpreted as a literal double quote, instead of as the end of the csv item. We can do that by telling `csv.reader` to interpret the caret as the escape character (see edited post).

Answer (score 0):

If you data is valid CSV you can use Python's csv.reader class. It should work just fine with your sample data. It may not work correctly depending an what an embeded double-quote looks like from the source system. See: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-contents.

Comment: Should have mentioned the file is a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem. You simply need to read in the file and remove any newline characters that occur between double quote characters.